# Getting the HWND of a widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I have a `QFrame` widget, and I need to get the HWND associated with it. Is there a way to get HWND of a widget in Qt?

Comment: Not all widgets have window handles

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [QWidget::winId()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qwidget.html#winId) to get the HWND associated with a widget.

Comment: Thanks,I'm very newbie, So I don't know how to do it, Please guide me.[This](http://pastebin.com/YQLPJSga) is my code. Where should I use QWidget::winId().

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It's OK to be newbie, but you need to know that this is a Q&A site, not a forum. That means that there is one question per post. If you have further questions, you need to make  a new post, not ask them in a comment. Also, this particular question has already been answered, so you should accept one the answers (click the green tick).

Comment: While top-level widgets always have a `HWND`, this is not restricted to top-level widgets alone. See [QWidget Class Reference - Native Widgets vs Alien Widgets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I edited my answer. So you can really get the HWND of any widget in Qt?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Except, what you call *the* HWND is really just *a* HWND. If one doesn't exist for a particular widget, Qt will create one behind your back. This also means, that you can get different values on subsequent calls.