# How to get a handle to standalone widget in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

How can I get widget pointer from WID (HWND) for widget that is standaone window? I tried:

```
     std::cout<<myWid<<std::endl;

             for (QWidget *widget : QApplication::allWidgets())
             {
                  std::cout<<widget->winId()<<std::endl;
                  if(widget->winId() == myWid)
                  {
                      std::cout<<"Found!"<<std::endl;
                  }
             }
```

And also:

```
     QWidget* theWidget = QWidget::find((WId)myWid);

     if (theWidget) 
     {
        std::cout<<"Found!"<<std::endl;
     }
```

But with no success. Is there any possibility for that?

Comment: What do you mean by standalone widget? How did you create it?

Comment: Note that depending on how t was created/used a `QWidget` needn't necessarily have a native window id associated with it -- see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets).  That could be one possible reason for `QWidget::find` failing.

Comment: Ok, but myWid os valid numer. Do why i fot null grom valid WID? Maybe is aby other way to retrieve a handler grom WID?

Comment: @Jankovsky222 Did you try searching for an answer containing QWidget and HWND?  This question, [Getting the HWND of a widget in qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652592/getting-the-hwnd-of-a-widget-in-qt) was one of the first things that came up when searching in a very popular web search engine.